# async/await: wait for loop end before return function result

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have next function:

```js
    async getPopular() {
      return await tryCatchWithApolloErrorAsync(async () => {
        const popular = await adminService
          .firestore()
          .collection(api.counters)
          .doc('companies-by-categories')
          .collection('categories')
          .get()

        let data: Popular[] = []

        popular.docs.map(element => {
          getCount(element.ref).then(count => {
            if (count > 0) {
              data.push({
                id: parseInt(element.id),
                amount: count
              })
            }
          })
        })

        return data
      })
    },
```

But it always return an empty array, even when inside map loop I have some data. How can I make it to wait for `popular.docs.map` to finish, before returning the empty `data` array?

Comment: `getCount` returns a promise. That promise does not call the `then` callback immediately, but later... after you have done the `return`. You should use `Promise.all` and await the resolution. So: `await Promise.all(popular.docs.map(element => { return getCount(.......`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `map` if you're not using its return value. There's no point in having your code create an array you're just immediately going to throw away.

If you want the calls to get the counts to run *in parallel*, you can use an array of promises from `map` with `Promise.all`:

```
async getPopular() {
  return await tryCatchWithApolloErrorAsync(async () => {
    const popular = await adminService
      .firestore()
      .collection(api.counters)
      .doc('companies-by-categories')
      .collection('categories')
      .get()

    let data: Popular[] = []

    await Promise.all(popular.docs.map(async element => { // `async` function
      const count = await getCount(element.ref)           // returns a promise
      if (count > 0) {
        data.push({
          id: parseInt(element.id),
          amount: count
        })
      }
    }))

    return data
  })
},
```

Or another way to do that is with `filter`:

```
async getPopular() {
  return await tryCatchWithApolloErrorAsync(async () => {
    const popular = await adminService
      .firestore()
      .collection(api.counters)
      .doc('companies-by-categories')
      .collection('categories')
      .get()

    let data: Popular[] = await Promise.all(popular.docs.map(async element => ({
      id: parseInt(element.id),
      count: await getCount(element.ref)
    })));

    return data.filter(({count}) => count > 0)
  })
},
```

If you want them to run sequentially, use a `for-of` loop:

```
async getPopular() {
  return await tryCatchWithApolloErrorAsync(async () => {
    const popular = await adminService
      .firestore()
      .collection(api.counters)
      .doc('companies-by-categories')
      .collection('categories')
      .get()

    let data: Popular[] = []

    for (const element of popular.docs) {
      const count = await getCount(element.ref)
      if (count > 0) {
        data.push({
          id: parseInt(element.id),
          amount: count
        })
      }
    }

    return data
  })
},
```